# Why the latest version of forge viewer V7.58 is only working with buffer geometry

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I recently started working on forge viewer. As the version of forge viewer I was using in my project was 7.2 and now I have updated it to V 7.58. Only the issue now I'm facing is, I'm unable to create extrude geometry with current version V 7.58.

- What the situation is -- I want to create lines (i.e. tubes with thickness, not the lines only) in the scene, So I have to create extrude geometry for that , but unable to create. I have verified with shape and material but not a problem with them. And if I try to create buffer geometry directly (i.e. excluding ExtrudeGeometry), then there is no any issue. Geometry is getting created.
- At at the lower versions of Forge viewer, I'm not facing such kind of issue. Its all working fine, extrude geometry also created fine.
- So my question is, Why latest version of forge viewer i.e. V7.58 is only working with buffer geometry ? Is this the issue with latest version of forge viewer really? If it is, How can I resolve it? Is there any source of documentation or anything else which will be helpful for such?

*unable to share the code*

Answer (score 0):

When working with Forge Viewer, you should be able to use both `THREE.Geometry` and `THREE.BufferGeometry`, but we would definitely recommend using the latter, as explained in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer. Not only is it a more efficient way of working with geometries, but since the viewer is based on a modified version of three.js version 71, some of the modifications (mainly performance optimizations) could affect the support for `THREE.Geometry` objects in the future.